# What is complaining in Islam?

Tags: practical-islam

What is the meaning of complaining can you show me examples of complaining I want to know so I won't complain to Allah is saying I want to have a normal life complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Why do we have such a small house?” 
“Why are we having this for dinner?” 
[To parents]: “You’re so annoying.” 
“I hate these clothes. They’re so ugly.”

Basically, being ungrateful is complaining to Allah.

Comment: So how do I know if I am being ungrateful or complaining to Allah?

Comment: @KavalySidibey When you’re hating on the blessings he’s giving you?

Comment: Is this complaining I want to have a normal life.

Comment: @KavalySidibey Depends. Though, I’d recommend making dua to Allah for at least improving your life because know that there’s people who have it worse than you.

Comment: So I wasn't complaining I was just asking for something?

Comment: @KavalySidibey over what context are you complaining this over?

Comment: Is saying I want to have a normal life complaining or being ungrateful?

Comment: @KavalySidibey if you have a decent life with decent luxuries like food, water, house, car, money, etc. and still are asking for a “normal life” then yes you’re being ungrateful.

Comment: What if I was being tested and said I want to have a normal life in my mind but not out my mouth will I still will Allah still test me or did I fail?

Comment: @KavalySidibey you only fail Allah’s test by giving up on Him and/or His religion.